# Chrome Version 62 CSS Visibility Tag Issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, visibility

div A is having visibility:- visible and inside the div there is another div B with visibility :- inherit

So the inside div should take 
     visibility:- visible 
but instead it is taking as hidden

This issue is happening only in Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit). In chrome 61 that was working fine Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Can you post a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5b0qsuge/

Comment: I can't reproduce too.  Plz use inspect element to discover the issue.

Comment: I don't see the issue either..

Comment: There is a bug report about this issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=778873&q=Visible&sort=-modified%20-m%20pri%20-stars&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified